# Powerpoint chart format codes (regex's cousin?)

Tags: regex, powerpoint

PowerPoint has what I think is a sort of rudimentary form of regex/string replacement feature called **format codes** for formatting values in a spreadsheet.  I'm trying to localize some numbers in a chart from a standard decimal format (27.5%) to a Spanish format (27,5%), where decimal points are replaced by commas.

I can't seem to simply swap the `.` for `,` in the correct decimal place.  I've tried lots of combinations like `%##\,##%` and `#00\,%` but nothing works exactly.  Any ideas?

*Partial* documentation: https://support.office.com/en-SG/article/Basic-number-format-codes-cda40649-36a1-4b8d-914a-09c79df24b0e

Comment: it would help to have an actual example file to look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, it doesn't seem to be regex too much. It is more formatting than regex. If you need to change decimal separator, you can use these options:

- change your system settings defined under the Regional and Language Settings,
- customize the separator used for decimals and thousands using Excel Options.

If there is another way, it would be nice to know.

[Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)

Comment: Thanks for replying.  i found that this works in one chart:  $##\,#0.0  but not in the chart I need to change.  Changing the system settings isn't an option.

Comment: I think you made him think that that number is a currency. Then to use two
numbers, display comma and then there is a decimal separator which is not
followed by any digit so it is not displayed. It sounds strange that it could
look O.k., even in one chart :-) More on these look here at [Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/264372), some examples can be found [here](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/NumberFormats.html).

Comment: What about other option, changing the settings of Excel.

Comment: I find Excel the best place to look for guidance on Format Codes. You make an apt comparison with regex because you can do a lot with these format codes. I suggest a google search on 'Excel format codes'. Full documentation is difficult to find A good overview is to be found here: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/custom-number-format.html

Comment: @ryuichiro: The last sentence of the documentation in your "here" link: If you live in a location that needs different codes, you can either design your own custom number formats, or hope that Microsoft has included them in your international version of Excel.  "Hope" is the key word there.  The closest I've come to a solution is %##\,##% or #00\,%, but that's not how it should be, but at least it puts the comma in the right place.

Comment: @itsmikem: You are right, many things seem to depend on hope regarding
Microsoft :-) It is sad that you cannot switch the decimal separator using
Excel Option after [opening your charts in Excel](http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/chartsdiagrams/2011/format-chart-data-labels-numbers-in-excel-mac.html). E.g., you could keep its look and appearance from the Excel file, selecting Keep Source Formatting & Link
Data.